# read array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am new in javascript and using nodejs and mongoose query to get a result which I would like to loop through and get some values in another array.

The resultset looks like

```
[ { _id: 5366e9049cfc825b32966852,
 companies:
     [ 5ab20bb69cb2754e949a09dc,
       5ac5d53983d45353bc6a9c54,
       5ac62eeca5421e4cb9abf63e]
},
{ _id: 5b9251f8ae8db624755f4b90,
 companies:
     [ 5b461c892bb9c81bd3ed4a25,
       5b5086196947782fbc873d28,
       5b76a6c79dc71a4a12564cc5 ]
}]
```

The final array should look like --

```
 [ 5ab20bb69cb2754e949a09dc,
   5ac5d53983d45353bc6a9c54,
   5ac62eeca5421e4cb9abf63e,
   5b461c892bb9c81bd3ed4a25,
   5b5086196947782fbc873d28,
   5b76a6c79dc71a4a12564cc5]
```

My code--

```
    Model.find().exec(function(err,gdoc){
          if(err)
          {
             callback({err:err,message:"Error looking up company"});
          }else
          {
             for (var i = 0, len = gdoc.length; i < len; i++) {                    
                    console.log(gdoc.companies);
              }
          }
    });
```

I am getting undefined values.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing one closing curly bracket for for loop. not solution but just saying

Comment: @NimitkumarShah Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `undefined` is that you try to access the non-existing `companies` property on `gdoc`. Instead of `gdoc.companies`, you have to use `gdoc[i].companies`.

Instead of your loop, you can use [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) together with the [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follows:

```js
const gdoc = [
  {
    _id: '5366e9049cfc825b32966852',
    companies: [
      '5ab20bb69cb2754e949a09dc',
      '5ac5d53983d45353bc6a9c54',
      '5ac62eeca5421e4cb9abf63e',
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: '5b9251f8ae8db624755f4b90',
    companies: [
      '5b461c892bb9c81bd3ed4a25',
      '5b5086196947782fbc873d28',
      '5b76a6c79dc71a4a12564cc5',
    ],
  },
];

const companies = [].concat(...gdoc.map(doc => doc.companies));
console.log(companies);
```

Comment: Brilliant. The only thing which I was getting is a red mark under three dots. Then I change the ES version in my editor and all good. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're trying to `concat`enate all the `company` fields of the results array. As long as you know that the key is `companies`, this is an easy reduction.

Arrays have a couple of builtin methods that make transforming them very easy, compared to having to use a for-loop.

`Array.forEach()`, `Array.map()`, `Array.reduce()` and `Array.find()` are the most frequently used ones.

```js
//  Since these id's contain letters as well, they need to be strings.
const data = [
  {
    _id: "5366e9049cfc825b32966852",
    companies:[
      "5ab20bb69cb2754e949a09dc",
      "5ac5d53983d45353bc6a9c54",
      "5ac62eeca5421e4cb9abf63e"
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5b9251f8ae8db624755f4b90",
   companies:[
    "5b461c892bb9c81bd3ed4a25",
    "5b5086196947782fbc873d28",
    "5b76a6c79dc71a4a12564cc5"
    ]
  }
];

const companies = data.reduce(( result, item ) => result.concat( item.companies ), []);

console.log( companies );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

`const map = [...[].concat(...arr.map((o) => o.companies))]`

```js
var arr = [ { _id: "5366e9049cfc825b32966852",
 companies:
     [ "5ab20bb69cb2754e949a09dc",
       "5ac5d53983d45353bc6a9c54",
       "5ac62eeca5421e4cb9abf63e"]
},
{ _id: "5b9251f8ae8db624755f4b90",
 companies:
     [ "5b461c892bb9c81bd3ed4a25",
       "5b5086196947782fbc873d28",
       "5b76a6c79dc71a4a12564cc5" ]
}];


const map = [...[].concat(...arr.map((o) => o.companies))]

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about running a reduce over the array.

```js
const model = [{
    _id: "5366e9049cfc825b32966852",
    companies: [
      "5ab20bb69cb2754e949a09dc",
      "5ac5d53983d45353bc6a9c54",
      "5ac62eeca5421e4cb9abf63e"
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5b9251f8ae8db624755f4b90",
    companies: [
      "5b461c892bb9c81bd3ed4a25",
      "5b5086196947782fbc873d28",
      "5b76a6c79dc71a4a12564cc5"
    ]
  }
];

const reducer = (acc, value) => {
  acc.push(...value.companies);
  return acc;
};

console.log(model.reduce(reducer, []));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like that!

```
var docs= [ { _id: "5366e9049cfc825b32966852",
 companies:
     [ "5ab20bb69cb2754e949a09dc",
       "5ac5d53983d45353bc6a9c54",
       "5ac62eeca5421e4cb9abf63e"]
},
{ _id: "5b9251f8ae8db624755f4b90",
 companies:
     [ "5b461c892bb9c81bd3ed4a25",
       "5b5086196947782fbc873d28",
       "5b76a6c79dc71a4a12564cc5" ]
}];
// your companies will be put in the folowing variable
var companies = [];

for ( var doc of docs){
    for (var item of doc.companies){
        companies.push(item)
    }
}

console.log(companies)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [ { _id: '5366e9049cfc825b32966852',
 companies:
     [ '5ab20bb69cb2754e949a09dc',
       '5ac5d53983d45353bc6a9c54',
       '5ac62eeca5421e4cb9abf63e']
},
{ _id: '5b9251f8ae8db624755f4b90',
 companies:
     [ '5b461c892bb9c81bd3ed4a25',
       '5b5086196947782fbc873d28',
       '5b76a6c79dc71a4a12564cc5' ]
}]
let outputArr = []
data.map(d => outputArr.push(d.companies));
//Flatten
console.log([].concat.apply([],outputArr))
```

Both **flatMap** and **flat** which are currently an '*experimental technology*' will allow a cleaner approach to this problem in the future. 
See:

**Array.prototype.flat()**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

**Array.prototype.flatMap()**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Answer (score -1):

You want something like this:

```js
var k = [{
    _id: "5366e9049cfc825b32966852",
    companies: ["5ab20bb69cb2754e949a09dc",
      "5ac5d53983d45353bc6a9c54",
      "5ac62eeca5421e4cb9abf63e"
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5b9251f8ae8db624755f4b90",
    companies: ["5b461c892bb9c81bd3ed4a25",
      "5b5086196947782fbc873d28",
      "5b76a6c79dc71a4a12564cc5"
    ]
  }
];

var res = [];
k.forEach(function(id) {
  res.push(...id.companies)
});


console.log(res);
```

Comment: This returns an array of arrays, OP wants an array of strings

Comment: This does not return an array of arrays since the three dots will spread the companies array into multiple values and array.push() accepts multiple arguments. My question would be, why use forEach() to mimic reduce() ?